# Reflect the content of a cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel-2007

I have a table that has 5 headers, namely - *Task, Percentage, Date of Completion, Status and Remarks*. 
Example:

`Task B should be Done by 04/14/2014, percentage 5.20%
Task C should be Done by 04/15/2014, percentage 7.70%`

**What I need to do:** 
E6 should always reflect the percentage of the task that has been most recently tagged as Done. Using the image above, for example, since Task B is already Done, E6 should reflect 5.20%. Once Task C is Done, E6 should reflect 7.70%. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

if the % are getting bigger and bigger then you could use this way:

In a column that you'll later hide, type for each line the formula: =IF(E2="Done";C2;""). Drag it downward for each line. You'll have only the % of the 'DONE' tasks, blank in the rest of them. For me this column is column A.

In cell E6 write: =MAX(A2:A5) to have the highest % among those "filtered for Done" with the formulas in column A.

[image]

If you want further info on the line with the highest done % use a VLookup formula.

Hope it helped...